# Server.MapPath falha dentro do Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net

No código abaixo, quando tento chamar a função MapPath dentro do Global.asax, ocorre um erro em tempo de execução com a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> System.Web.HttpException (0×80004005): Request is not available in
>   this context.

O código com defeito é:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    string path = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/assets/all.js")

    // ... code
}
```

Como usar uma função MapPath no Global.asax?

Answer (score 6):

O problema está de fato no `HttpContext.Server.MapPath`. O problema ocorre pois quando chamado no `Application_Start`, não há um contexto Http. Esse contexto só existe quando há um chamado HTTP.

O Application_Start ocorre apenas quando sua aplicação web é iniciada via Start/Restart no IIS, reciclando o App Pool, entre outras formas. Como não há um contexto HTTP, você deve usar o contexto do ambiente.

Troque o HttpContext para `HostingEnvironment.MapPath`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    string path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/assets/all.js")

    // ... code
}
```

O próprio Server.MapPath() chama o HostingEnvironment.MapPath(). A única diferença que importa no contexto dessa pergunta é que você precisa certificar que a string passada no parâmetro nunca é nula, senão uma Exception será disparada.

Comment: Nota: O antes utilizado `HttpContext.Current` passou a não estar disponível no `Application_Start` na versão 7 do IIS. Se a aplicação estiver hospedada em uma versão anterior ou no modo *classic* o contexto estará disponível. Mas claro, não recomendo essa dependência :)

Answer (score 1):

O `HttpContext` é apenas disponível quando alguém faz um chamado HTTP (como ir no site por meio de um browser).

Nesse sentido, não é possível usar a função como descrito, no lugar onde se encontra no `Application_Start`. Entretanto, mesmo sabendo que a pergunta é a respeito do `Global.ascx`, a linha

```
string path = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/assets/all.js")
```

é código completamente válido se estiver usado dentro de um `Controller` ou `View` (usando `MVC`) ou o `Code Behind` (usando webforms do `ASP.NET`).

Answer (score -1):

Tente:

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath();
```